# How to pass url parameter into an Analytic Dashboard in Salesforce Lightning Page

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-einstein

I am trying to display an analytic dashboard in lightning community page.

When i drag the analytic dashboard component into the lightning community page. I see the below option. How can i replace the hardcoded Id with the value from url parameter?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone facing the same issue. You can just specify the parameter like this {!campaignId} and passing this value through url by passing adding this into the url /?campaignId=7012g00000ZkSJiAAN

[image]